# Problems ordering CPT by custom field DATE

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF plugin, and is for and archive template.

I'm trying to order my custom post type 'concerts' using a custom field named 'data_del_concert', configured as yyyymmdd, but I'm not able.

````
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
          'posts_per_page'    => -1,
          'post_type'         => 'concerts',
          'meta_key'          => 'data_del_concert',
          'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
          'meta_type'         => 'DATE',
          'order'             => 'ASC'
        ));
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  ```

I'm trying a lot of possibilities but I don't find the good one!!

Thanks in advance
````

Comment: could you try `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` ?

Comment: and maybe even `'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',`

Comment: thanks for you reply. Doesn't work for me